# please hold: a country’s job

Tags: story, cryptic-clues

It’s been a while, huh?

You have a job now.

Surfing through the U.N.’s (or is it UN’s) papers to sort them.

Oh, a new pack of ‘em.

1)

Germany said today some words:
follows:

The is, indeed (4)
Ice, but from Iceland (2)
Before the first letter (1)
He studies a rufous book (3)
When I called the bad German, he said “gerund” (7)

2)

Russia said some words:

Где моя шляпа?

Найдите его, пожалуйста.

Please, don’t take that wrong :)

3)

Some countries talked about themselves.

They’re the primary suspects of Rus, prob incorr.

Mor came and stated that he di’nt hae tha ‘at.
**(Note: written by Sco, try to fig out)**

Gre stae tha ‘e di’nt hae it. Soulvaki [*sic*] tasted like deceit.

Chn stae tha s’e di’nt hae it. Dump’ins tasted like deceit.

4)

Okay, we have the culprit, but all he had was cryptic needlepoint.

Ma

0, Abbas is at his home while ticking away. (5)

0, Olaf has his small cat is named Chen. (7)

1, Myfanwy in Florida, with Greek eggs, they are! (5)

0, Johannes is very into number systems, that’s what he meant. (8)

0, Johnny is in a room ghosts hate. (6,4)

**WHICH COUNTRY DID THE HEINOUS CRIME OF NO MORE HABERDASHERY?**

NOTES: Russia is saying,

> Where is my hat? Please find it!

HINTS:

> There are 200 suspects, all of them countries. Remember, countries, unlike molecules, act as their constituent parts, such as cities.

> @cap is right thus far, now he should just apply the other cryptics! Names don’t matter… and remember Ma in the context of music!

Comment: Yes, we have gotten a reboot. Did I ask?

Answer (score 1):

Very partial answer...

*Germany said today some words: follows:*

> the following clues seem to be cryptic-like plays on words, some involving Germany or German. Like cryptic clues, each clue seems to clue the answer in two different ways. However, unlike a strict cryptic clue where words are either part of the definition or part of the wordplay, words in the clues may serve both purposes.

*The is, indeed (4)*

> **THIS** *The is* sounds like *this*. *Indeed* can slangily be expressed by the word *this*.

*Ice, but from Iceland (2)*

> **IS** is Icelandic for 'ice' and is also the ISO code for Iceland.

*Before the first letter (1)*

> **A** The first letter of 'before' is *B*. *Before* that (in the alphabet) is *A*. *A* is also the *first letter* of the alphabet.

*He studies a rufous book (3)*

> **RED** *Rufous* means *red*. *Red* also sounds like *read* (past tense) which looks like *read* (present tense) which is how one studies a book.

*When I called the bad German, he said “gerund” (7)*

> **HERRING** *Herr* is German for 'mister' which non-German-speakers may associate with the address *Herr Hitler* (the bad German). "[gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)" means to add *ing*.

*Russia said some words:*

*Где моя шляпа?*

*Найдите его, пожалуйста.*

*Please, don’t take that wrong :)*

> The Russian means "Where is my hat? Find it, please." All the letters of "MY HAT" resemble Russian Cyrillic letters "мунат" (pronounced roughly MUNAT) but I'm not sure what to make of it...

Comment: No, sevtion one is right. You just have to figure out which country has his hat, where, and maybe why.